# Is it safe to put pin of debit card in worldpay?

Tags: visa, world

I am buying from proxybonanza.com that accept worldpay.

Then I go to this screen:

[image]

Looks like they managed to figure out that the bank is USbank without me having to tell them. In fact, they know which bank issue payments.

But this asking for pin number worries me.

Can I trust worldpay.com?

Can people make a copy of my card and drain my debit card payment.

The payment is declined nevertheless. Another card is successful though. This time they automatically knows my phone number on file and send SMS to it. Impressive big brothers I must admit.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The PIN sure looks fishy. Why a PIN ? The 3 digit code should be enough. Did you try clicking submit without the PIN ?

Comment: no. can anyone make a duplicate of my card, and use the pin to dry it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read about it more [here](http://istvn.blogspot.com/2010/02/verified-by-visa-legit-or-phish.html). (Summary: Verified by Visa and SecureSuite.net is legit.) That said, I wouldn't share my ATM PIN online regardless.

Comment: should I change my pin? I'll leave $500 there for a while.

Comment: Verified by Visa is legit, as in "operated by Visa", but it's not exactly endorsed by the security community in general as the epitome of good practices, and trains you in bad security practices (typing PINs into unexpected popups, etc). Some researchers have questioned whether participating in it might actually increase your risk, depending on bank liability provisions etc. And, from the theoretical perspective, adding more "secret numbers" on the form isn't nearly as good of a security enhancement as real two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a real credit card for better protections against fraud guaranteed by the Fair Credit Billing Act. Many issuers go beyond what is required. American Express and Chase (in that order) are generally regarded the top two in dispute resolution.

Verified by Visa is a visa program that your bank as to participate in. The verification supposedly is carried out by the bank, and your phone number is naturally known by the bank. It really provides no benefits to the customer (in the US) due to the above protections.

Answer (score 2):

I have a visa debit card that also uses "verified by Visa" and it does not ask for my pin. Asking for a pin is certainly not required by "verified by Visa"

It used to use my bank's login information and has since changed to a unique verified by Visa password.